# Is there an R library that estimates a multivariate natural cubic spline (or similar) function?

Tags: r, interpolation, spline

*note:* originally posted on [Cross Validated (stats SE)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/is-there-an-r-or-matlab-python-or-other-function-that-estimates-a-multivariat) on 07-26-2011, with no correct answers to date.

**Background**

I have a model, *f*, where *Y=f(**X**)*

***X*** is an *n x m*  matrix of samples from *m* parameters and *Y* is the *n x 1* vector of model outputs.

*f* is computationally intensive, so I would like to approximate *f* using a multivariate cubic spline through *(**X**,Y)* points, so that I can evaluate *Y* at a larger number of points.

**Question**

Is there an R function that will calculate an arbitrary relationship between *X* and *Y*?

Specifically, I am looking for a multivariate version of the `splinefun` function, which generates a spline function for the univariate case.

e.g. this is how `splinefun` works for the univariate case

```
x <- 1:100
y <- runif(100)
foo <- splinefun(x,y, method = "monoH.FC")
foo(x) #returns y, as example
```

The test that the function interpolates exactly through the points is successful:

```
all(y == foo(1:100))
## TRUE
```

**What I have tried**

I have reviewed the [mda](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mda/index.html) package, and it seems that the following should work:

```
library(mda)
x   <- data.frame(a = 1:100, b = 1:100/2, c = 1:100*2)
y   <- runif(100)
foo <- mars(x,y)
predict(foo, x) #all the same value
```

however the function does not interpolate exactly through the design points:

```
all(y == predict(foo,x))
## FALSE
```

I also could not find a way to implement a cubic-spline in either the `gam`, `marss`, or `earth` packages.

Answer (score 4):

Actually several packages can do it. The one I use is the "rms" package which has `rcs`, but the survival package also has `pspline` and the splines package has the `ns` function {}. "Natural splines" (constructed with ns) are also cubic splines. You will need to form multivariate fitting function with the '*' operator in the multivariate formula creating "crossed" spline terms.
that the example you offered was not sufficiently rich.

I guess I am confused that you want exact fits. R is a statistical package. Approximate estimation is the goal. Generally exact fits are more of a problem because they lead to multicollinearity.

Comment: I want to use the function to create an emulator of a multivariate likelihood surface, so that I can estimate a posterior distribution using MCMC in a reasonable amount of time (avoiding a >1hr model run at each step).

Comment: I have increased the number of samples in the example.

Comment: `ns` does not seem to accept a multivariate matrix as an argument `?ns` says that `x` is "the predictor variable" (presumably indicating univariate). Could you provide an example?

Comment: You need to supply the matrix to a regression function that takes the splines as terms in the formula. You need a spline function for each variable. You get a model that can be turned into predictions in the range of the variables. Harrell's "Regression Modeling Strategies" has several worked examples in his chapter on logistic regression. In your example you only gave 100 values for y, whereas you would need to supply 100 X 100 values associated with various combinations (typically using expand grid) to fit a surface with values in a 2-D range.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the DiceKriging package which was developed to undertake tasks like this.
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DiceKriging/index.html

I've provided an example application at
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13510/fitting-multivariate-natural-cubic-spline/65012#65012

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is precisely what you are looking for, but you could try Tps() in the R package fields. It's meant for doing thin-plate splines interpolations (2D equivalent of cubic splines) for spatial data, but will take up to four covariates, although it will expect them to be euclidean x,y,z + time, so you need to be clear that you are selecting the correct options for your particular case. If you want to interpolate, set the smoothing parameter lambda to zero. You might also try the function polymars() in the R package polspline.