# interpolate in a 3 dimensional spline in R

Tags: r, interpolation, spline, loess

I would like to fit a surface to some values:

```
x = 1:10
y = 10:1
z = sample(1:10,10)
```

I would like to fun something like `spline_function(z ~ x + y)`. The actual spline functions in R seem to take only `x` and `y` so that i cannot have a two dimensional x coordinate.  What is the way to do this in R? I am aware of `loess` for local polynomials etc. but splines is really what I am looking for.

Comment: This question might answer yours...? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142180/is-there-an-r-library-that-estimates-a-multivariate-natural-cubic-spline-or-sim

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One good option is the **mgcv** package which comes with all versions of R. It has isotropic penalised regression splines of two or more variables via `s()` and anisotropic penalised regression splines of two or more variables via tensor products and `te()`.

If you don't want penalised regression splines, you can use argument `fx = TRUE` to fix known degree of freedom splines.

Here is an example from `?te`

```
# following shows how tensor pruduct deals nicely with 
# badly scaled covariates (range of x 5% of range of z )
require(mgcv)
test1 <- function(x, z ,sx=0.3, sz=0.4) { 
  x <- x*20
  (pi ** sx * sz) * (1.2 * exp(-(x - 0.2)^2 / sx^2 - ( z - 0.3)^2 / sz^2) +
  0.8 * exp(-(x - 0.7)^2 / sx^2 -(z - 0.8)^2 / sz^2))
}
n <- 500

old.par<-par(mfrow=c(2,2))
x <- runif(n) / 20
z<-runif(n)
xs <- seq(0, 1, length=30) / 20
zs <- seq(0, 1, length=30)
pr <- data.frame(x=rep(xs, 30), z=rep(zs, rep(30, 30)))
truth <- matrix(test1(pr$x, pr$z), 30, 30)
f <- test1(x, z)
y <- f + rnorm(n) * 0.2

## model 1 with s() smooths
b1 <- gam(y ~ s(x,z))
persp(xs, zs, truth)
title("truth")
vis.gam(b1)
title("t.p.r.s")

## model 2 with te() smooths
b2 <- gam(y ~ te(x, z))
vis.gam(b2)
title("tensor product")

## model 3 te() smooths specifying margin bases
b3 <- gam(y ~ te(x, z, bs=c("tp", "tp")))
vis.gam(b3)
title("tensor product")
par(old.par)
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if there is a better option, I have implemented this idea for a function which have more less the same shape than the one displayed and found a very poor performance near the boundary. This also happens in this example near x~0.