# Multiple Linear Regression and Interpolation

Tags: r, regression, interpolation

I'm trying to understand multiple regression and interpolation.  Ideally, to solve this problem I'd like to build a regression model, then based on those results interpret a function (e.g. cubic spline) that would all me to fill in some missing data points.

As an example, say I have two data sets: (1) Monthly weather data from data set A that I know is accurate; and (2) Monthly weather data from 5 weather stations located within the region of the data set A that may not be as accurate but still need to be accounted for.

The idea here is to regress data from A on to the 5 weather stations in B, then interpret a function that would allow me to fill in for daily weather over the month.  Obviously the data is going to be very closely related, but this may not be the case in other data as elevation and distances may be an issue.  For now, I'm focusing on the simpler problem.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this so I would appreciate any help.

Here is some R code I've started working on:

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(y = c(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 70)), 
                       s1 = c(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 70)),
                       s2 = c(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 70)),
                       s3 = c(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 70)),
                       s4 = c(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 70)),
                       s5 = c(rnorm(n = 12, mean = 70)))
```

Regression:

```
fit <- lm(y ~ s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5, data = df)
summary(fit)
plot(fit)
```

Results:

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 + s5, data = df)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.3776 -0.8447 -0.0696  0.6876  1.7822 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 66.29509   86.26241   0.769    0.471
s1          -0.52117    0.40535  -1.286    0.246
s2          -0.08553    0.54861  -0.156    0.881
s3          -0.20059    0.41261  -0.486    0.644
s4           0.34394    0.54888   0.627    0.554
s5           0.51401    0.42146   1.220    0.268

Residual standard error: 1.368 on 6 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.4482,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.01167 
F-statistic: 0.9746 on 5 and 6 DF,  p-value: 0.5009
```

Comment: So do you want to fill in missing `y` values on the basis of known `s1-s5` values? You want `predict` in this case, e.g.: `df$y[5:6] <- NA; fit <- lm(y ~ ., data=df); predict(fit, newdata=df)` - this will give a `y` value returned for each and every row regardless of whether it was `NA` in the original data. This is a straight-line linear fit though, not a cubic spline.

Comment: In fact, I want to fill in missing data for each of the stations because of their proximity to each other.  This could give a better representation of the actual weather.  Yes that is easier, but I need to incorporate a spline to account for variability during the day.  Any idea?

Comment: Does this help? [Is there an R library that estimates a multivariate natural cubic spline (or similar) function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142180/is-there-an-r-library-that-estimates-a-multivariate-natural-cubic-spline-or-sim)

Comment: @thelatemail It is a start.  I'll have a read of these and a few related posts.  Thnks.