# 3D Hermite cubic spline interpolation in R

Tags: r, interpolation, spline, cubic, hermite

I have a dataframe composed of three numeric variables (x,y,z) which are the coordinates of a 3D surface obtained from `interp2xyz` from the `akima` package.

`x     y    z
0.600 0.02 42.801
0.604 0.02 42.527
0.609 0.02 42.253
0.614 0.02 41.979
0.618 0.02 41.705
0.623 0.02 41.430
... ... ...`

I want to perform an Hermite cubic spline (eg. z=f(x,y)) saving the function into a variable in the same fashion as `splinefun()` or `approxfun()` do, so that I can use it later with (x,y) inputs. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an R library that estimates a multivariate natural cubic spline (or similar) function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7142180/is-there-an-r-library-that-estimates-a-multivariate-natural-cubic-spline-or-sim)